# Sha256 Mismatch for pip install on fresh docker image

Tags: python, docker, caching, pip, requirements

I am trying to create a docker image with a bunch of python libraries.

On doing a `pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt`, it keeps failing with mismatched hashes for libraries, especially pyspark.

The failure message looks like -

```
ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
    pyspark==2.4.6 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/e4/5c15ab8d354c4e3528510821865e6748209a9b0ff6a1788f4cd36cc2a5dc/pyspark-2.4.6.tar.gz#sha256=b4b319a3ffd187a3019f654ae1c8ac38048bcec2940f8cecdef829302d166feb (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)):
        Expected sha256 b4b319a3ffd187a3019f654ae1c8ac38048bcec2940f8cecdef829302d166feb
             Got        e15b72fe55a366df7329932882c56328874152cf618950c7ce45e11f1c9dc5d1
```

Some stuff that I have already tried, consulting other stack overflow threads -

1. Remove `__pycache__` and `~/.cache/` directories.
2. Downgrade pip to 20.0.2, since there were threads saying that this was caused by pip20.1.0
3. Also tried using `--no-cache-dir` as you can see.
4. Build the docker image without caching using - `docker build --no-cache . -t labydock-image`

The Dockerfile looks something like this -

```
FROM python:3.7.7-stretch

USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openjdk-8-jdk

WORKDIR /labyrinth
COPY ./dodo.py .
COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install pip==20.0.2

RUN rm -rf ~/.cache
RUN rm -rf __pycache__

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

And the corresponding requirements.txt file looks like this -

```
mockito==1.2.1
py4j==0.10.7
pypandoc==1.5
pyspark==2.4.6
pytest
pandas
doit
koalas
requests
presto-client
mysql-connector-python
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Please let me know if you need more details

Comment: What docker image are you inheriting `FROM`? What does your `requirements.txt` file look like?

Comment: @Omer Added these details.

Comment: Interesting, the Dockerfile builds successfully on my machine

Comment: Try `docker build --no-cache .`, maybe one of the intermediate layers is corrupt

Comment: can you try with `docker build -t --no-cache my_image .`

Comment: Tried building the docker image without cache. Did not work. :(

Comment: Try, on your host machine, to run `curl https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/e4/5c15ab8d354c4e3528510821865e6748209a9b0ff6a1788f4cd36cc2a5dc/pyspark-2.4.6.tar.gz > temp.bin` then run `sha256sum temp.bin`. What do you get?

Comment: ```shasum temp.bin``` gives the following output - ```fd8707942264863bcc635f3ab7a6a1ec9b47784d  temp.bin``` ( On a mac. Hence had to use shasum. )

Answer (score 1):

After much deliberation, I could figure this out with the help of a colleague.

Our Root cause analysis is as follows - When we download a library, the server itself sends a SHA to be verified post download, to prevent tampering with the library. Now, due to **poor internet** connection, the library was getting corrupted while downloading and hence the sha mismatch happened. It sounds incredibly weird to me since I assumed pip would have detected this failure and prompted that the library download failed.

Anyway, we ran the same docker image on a VM and it worked like a charm.